# Can awk find a field containing a string from a list?

Tags: awk, find

I have a file containing different fields.
I have another file containing a list of different words.
I need to use awk command to extract from my 1st file all records where a specific field contains one or different words from my 2nd file.

For example 1st file:

```
Feb 15 12:05:10 lcif adm.slm: root [23416]: cd /tmp
Feb 15 12:05:24 lcif adm.slm: root [23416]: cat tst.sh
Feb 15 12:05:44 lcif adm.slm: root [23416]: date
Feb 15 12:05:52 lcif adm.pse: root [23419]: rm -f file
Feb 15 12:05:58 lcif adm.pse: root [23419]: who
Feb 15 12:06:02 lcif adm.pse: root [23419]: uptime
Feb 15 12:06:56 lcif adm.pse: root [23419]: reboot
Feb 15 12:06:58 lcif adm.pse: root [23419]: ls -lrt
```

For example 2nd file:

```
rm
reboot
shutdown
```

Then awk command should returns:

```
Feb 15 12:05:52 lcif adm.pse: root [23419]: rm -f file
Feb 15 12:06:56 lcif adm.pse: root [23419]: reboot
```

Tried deperatly with array/map.

Tried this to:

```
awk -F ": " '{if ($3 ~ "^rm" || $3 ~ "^reboot" || $3 ~ "^shutdown") print}'
```

But the list of words I'm looking for is getting bigger and bigger.
I'd rather use a file list.

Appreciate any help.

Thank you !
Serge

Comment: consider running a web search on `awk match strings from one file to another file`, or `awk find matches between files` or `awk match list against file` ... lots of matches including many from `stackoverflow.com` and its sister sites

Comment: If you do not have to use AWK AT ANY PRICE, then I suggest looking at `-f FILE` option in [`grep` man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/grep)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

don't waste time with arrays. just dynamically generate hard-coded `regex` on the fly :

```
printf '%s' "${file_a}" | 

gawk -p-             -b 'BEGIN { FS = "[]]: " } '"$(

 awk -v  __="${file_b}" 'BEGIN { 

    FS = RS  ;    OFS = "|"
    RS = "^$"; _= ORS =  ""

    $_ = __

    print "$NF ~ \"^(" $(_*(NF-=_==$NF)) ")( |$)\"" }' )"
```

> 

```
Feb 15 12:05:52 lcif adm.pse: root [23419]: rm -f file
Feb 15 12:06:56 lcif adm.pse: root [23419]: reboot
```

> 

```
# this part being dynamically generated

awk 'BEGIN { FS = "[]]: " } $NF ~ "^(rm|reboot|shutdown)( |$)" '
```

then instead of looping through an array, it'll be a high speed single pass  through `file A` without having to store any rows in between

Comment: Why not use a simple `pasted -sd '|' file_b` for generating the `rm|reboot|shutdown` string?

Comment: sure … isn't it `paste` not a past tense of it?

Answer (score 3):

You might do it like this:

```bash
awk -F ': ' '
    FNR == NR { commands[$0]; next }
    split($3,cmdline," ") && (cmdline[1] in commands)
' file2 file1
```

output:

```
Feb 15 12:05:52 lcif adm.pse: root [23419]: rm -f file
Feb 15 12:06:56 lcif adm.pse: root [23419]: reboot
```